# So I opened it to make it more inviting

Tags: sentence-meaning, phrase-request

No one had touched the box of chocolates that I had brought, so I opened it **to make it more inviting.**

Does the highlighted part make sense in the context? Can I use "inviting"?

Comment: I sometimes try to piece together what someone is reading or writing about from their questions... You jump straight from "sucide by hanging" to handing out chocolate.

Comment: It's up to you to say what you *mean*, but if it was me, I might consider alternatives such as ***handy, approachable, available, accessible,...*** There's a difference between ***inviting, appealing, enticing*** and ***accessible, easy to help oneself to**,* and the latter makes more sense to me in this context.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica In that case you'd be saying something different from what OP was expressing. Okay and all that, but only as long as you are certain that what OP meant to say was what you believe OP ought to have meant to say.

Comment: I would eat one too, so that others are not the first. Sometimes, people don't like to be the first one to enjoy, or to take the last chocolate.

Answer (score 1):

From the dictionary "offering the promise of an attractive or enjoyable experience."

So if opening the box makes it appear more attractive and encourages people to enjoy the chocolates, then "inviting" is a good word to choose.